# Central manifold theorem results in null series

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have the following system of ODEs:

$\dot u = v$

$\dot v = -v + \beta uv$

I am supposed to study the stability of the equilibrium using the Central Manifold Theorem.

I begin by changing coordinates, getting the following system:

$\dot x = -x + \beta x (-x + y) = f(x,y)$

$\dot y = \beta x (-x + y) = g(x,y)$

The linear term is in $x$, so I use $h(y) = $ a polynomial of $n$th order. Solving the equation $-f(h,y) + h'g(h,y) = 0$, I get a null polynomial $h$.

My question is the following: under the central limit theorem, what does it mean to get a null $h$? According to the book I'm using (*), $h$ should be a non-null polynomial of at least order $2$, and I don't see what's different between this system and any other system used in the examples.

(*): Guckenheimer & Holmes; *Nonlinear Oscillations, Dynamical Systems, and Bifurcations of Vector Fields*; Springer (1983)

Comment: Which equilibrium? All points $(u,0)$ count.

Answer (score 1):

Follows a MATHEMATICA script showing the procedure to calculate the central manifold which is stable.

```
n = 5;
V = Sum[a[k] u^k, {k, 1, n}];
res = D[V, u] V + V - beta u V;
equs = CoefficientList[res, u];
equs0 = Take[equs, {2, n + 1}];

sola = Solve[equs0 == 0, Table[a[k], {k, 1, n}]][[2]]

V0 = V /. sola

gr0 = StreamPlot[{v, -v + beta u v} /. {beta -> -1}, {u, -2, 2}, {v, -2, 2}];
gr1 = Plot[V0 /. {beta -> -1}, {u, -2, 2}, PlotStyle -> Red];
Show[gr0, gr1]
```

[image]

NOTE

The central manifold has the dynamics

$$
\dot u + u = \frac{\beta}{2}u^2
$$

or

$$
u = \frac{2}{\beta+e^{t+2c_0}}
$$

Answer (score 1):

Insert the first equation into the second
$$
\dot v = -\dot u + \beta u\dot u
$$
which integrates for the solution through the origin to
$$
v=-u+\frac\beta2u^2.
$$